# what does shapely_object.bounds do?

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

I am working with folium and shapely, and just came across a keyword named as **bounds**. Can anyone explain what does it exactly do.
I found an explanation but i dont understand the point behind it : *circle_geom.bounds is the bounding box of the circle geometry, which is a tuple of (minx, miny, maxx, maxy) coordinates.*

Answer (score 2):

One application could be if you wanted to place a smaller object within a larger object in the direct center.

For example, if you know the max and min x and y of your larger shape, and the same for another shape you wish to place in the direct center of your larger shape, simple calculations can place the smaller object within the larger object in that perfect center.

Does that help?